# PostgreSQL: boolean + integer

Tags: postgresql, integer, boolean, type-conversion

I have a query like:

```
SELECT (column LIKE 'string')+100
```

It returns ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean + integer

I couldn't find a function to convert bool to int, there is only text to int: to_number().

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: What do you want the boolean `true` or boolean `false` to be casted as?

Comment: Both, it depends on result of clause between (). I need to get integer - 0 or 1.

Comment: does (column like 'string')::integer + 100` work? otherwise use `CASE WHEN .. THEN`

Comment: thanx a lot @vol7tron, ::integer worked well for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Conditional Expressions, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-conditional.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a string comparison to 1 when true and 0 when false, you could use a case statement:

```
select case when column like '%foo%' then 1 else 0 end as my_int from my_table;
```

If you wanted to add to that result, you would do something like:

```
select (case when column like '%foo%' then 1 else 0 end) + 100 as my_int from my_table;
```

Comment: I don't believe so, but if for some reason you find you need to do this kind of thing often, you could put it in a function: 

 create function matches(text, text) RETURNS integer AS $$ 
  select case when $1 like $2 then 1 else 0 end
 $$ LANGUAGE SQL;

Then your sql would be

    select matches(column, '%foo%') + 100 from my_table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (column LIKE 'string')::integer +100
```

Comment: Could you provide a reference for ::integer?

Comment: @Mansoor, check [section 4.2.9](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) of docs.

Answer (score 1):

I needed more portable solution, so this one suits me the best:

```
SELECT CAST((column LIKE 'string') AS integer)+100
```